# Dynamically incresing the no of lines in editText

Tags: java, android

I have a layout with an editText field.I have to fit a large amount of data by default in the text box while loading it initially.
Since i fit the data dynamically onCreate i dont know the size of the data initially.
Can somebody tell me how can i increase the height of the editText field(Include multiple lines on large data) dynamically?

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="About me :"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/dboard_classwall_txt_color" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/text_about_me"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="34dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/editbox_profile_bg"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                    android:maxLength="@integer/roster_max_contact_details_length"
                    android:minHeight="50dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/edit_prof_editbox_txt_color"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null" >

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

`android:layout_height="34dp"` => `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` 
 `android:singleLine="true"` => `android:singleLine="false"`

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
<EditText
                    android:id="@+id/text_about_me"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/editbox_profile_bg"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                    android:minHeight="50dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/edit_prof_editbox_txt_color"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null" >
```

instead hope it helps